# Standard deviation of the sum of a discrete uniform

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, uniform-distribution

If I randomly generate a number between 1 and 10.... 10 times, and then total all the numbers, what will the standard deviation of that total be?

I'm pretty sure the mean of the total will be 55.5, but what about the average distance from that mean?

Comment: Are the numbers drawn from a uniform distribution? Are you drawing integers only, or any continuous value within that interval?

Comment: using python for this:   num = random.randint(1,10)     which just generates a random integer between one and 10.  I'm not sure if that's a uniform dist, but it's definitely just integers

Comment: That's uniform.  Each number has the same probability of being returned from `randint` as any other.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Apply [Basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) to [variance of discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) and take the square root. You get $\sqrt{n(f^2-1)/12}$ where $f$ is the number of outcomes and $n$ is the number of discrete uniforms. So for f=n=10 that's $\sqrt{990/12}$ or about 9.083. This formula is given in several posts on site relating to the variance of a sum of die rolls.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the average.

Using the expectation operator $E$, this is a consequence of the *linearity* of expectation.  If we write $X$ for a random integer between one and ten drawn inclusively and uniformly (this is what the function call `random.randint` is modeling), then

$$ E(X) = 1 \times 0.1 + 2 \times 0.1 + \cdots + 10 * 0.1 = 5.5 $$

You're asking about the sum of ten draws from $X$, so using the linearity of expectation

$$ E \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{10} X \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{10} E(X) = 10 E(X) = 5.5 $$

The variance calculation is a little more tricky, but goes through with a standard trick.  For clarity, let's assign each of your ten draws to a different symbol, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{10}$ are the ten draws from $X$.  Now recall that for *any* two random variables $A$ and $B$

$$ Var(A + B) = Var(A) + Var(B) + 2Cov(A, B) $$

The variance is *not* linear, its failure to be linear is summarized in the $Cov(A, B)$ term that appears.

In your case, you need to know that when you call `random.randint` multiple times, the draws you get are *independent*.  This is really important, the random number generator would be useless if this was not true.  For $A$ and $B$ *independent* random variables

$$ Cov(A, B) = 0 $$

Again, super important, must be independent or this step probably fails.

Given all this, you can break down the variance

$$ Var \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) + 2 \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n Cov(X_i, X_j) $$

You should play around with that until you convince yourself it's true.  The index manipulation is a little weird until you get used to it.  Anyway, in our situation, the covariance terms are zero, so this reduces to

$$ Var \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} Var(X_i) $$

But each $X_i$ has the same distribution, so this is really just

$$ Var \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{10} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X) = 10 Var(X) $$

And my guess is you can finish it off from here.

Comment: Are you thinking this is a homework assignment?

Comment: Oh, no I wasn't.  Eep, maybe got carried away!

Comment: If it isn't, you could probably tell the OP the answer, rather than leaving it for him to finish.  I can ask the OP if it's HW.

Comment: Yah, I know I could, that was an editorial decision on my part.  Do you disagree @gung (always value your opinion).

Comment: I was going to provide a short post that just gave the number--a straightforward answer to a straightforward question. It isn't clear to me that this is HW, & the OP doesn't seem to be very familiar w/ the uniform, so this may be difficult to work through. It's your call, though.

Comment: Well, I suppose I'll leave it and let the poster decide if it's helpful.  Please feel free to post a more succinct answer if you'd  like (not really my strength I suppose).  @rikkitikkitumbo please let me know if this answer is helpful or overkill.

Comment: mmm.. I think it's great how much you put here.  This wasn't really HW, and I don't REALLY need to know the answer, so the lazier part of me thinks "...sooo.... what's the answer?"   But another part of me thinks "Someday if I ever want to know more I can look at that guy's answer to my post".  That being said... my guess is that the answer is roughly: (5.5*.99)/3 * 10   or about 18.  What is Var(x)?  The stddev of x? I got the 3 thinking that 3 stdevs each way will give you 98% of all the data in a normal dist?  Anyway... uh.. what's the answer? :)